# Java variable not changed, even after reference it was pointing to got changed

Tags: java, variables, scope

I am trying to assign value in result.next but somehow value is not getting changed when i=1 iteration is finished.

Initially result is null.

First iteration when i is 0, result.next points to ListNode(10)

when i=1 has finished execution i am expecting value of result.next to ListNode(2), because it has reference of temp.

```
public void Mymethod() {
        ListNode result = null;
        ListNode temp = new ListNode(10);
        int j = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    j++;
                    result = new ListNode(1);
                    result.next = temp;
                    continue;
                }
                temp = new ListNode(2);
            }
        }
    }
class ListNode {
    public int val;
    public ListNode next;

    ListNode(int x) {
        val = x;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vipin Please run this code again after that you have changed the condition in inner loop. It should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...because it has reference of temp.

No, it has a *copy* of the reference that was *in* `temp` as of the `result.next = temp` line. But there is no ongoing link between `result.next` and `temp`. Later when you do `temp = new ListNode(2)`, that changes the value of `temp` to a new reference, which has no effect whatsoever on `result.next`.

After the `result.next = temp` line in the first iteration of your inner loop, here's (roughly) what we have in memory:

```
[temp: Ref11243]−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                          |
                                          |
                                          |
                                          |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                          + −−>| ListNode   |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
[result: Ref89895]−−−>|    ListNode    |  |    | val: 10    |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |    | next: null |
                      | val: 1         |  |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | next: Ref11243 |−−+
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note that `result` and `temp` both contain the same value, a reference to the `ListNode` you created at the top (I've shown it in the above as `Ref11243`, but we never see or need to see the actual value).

But then when you do this:

```
temp = new ListNode(2);
```

you have this instead:

```
                                              +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
[temp: Ref68545]−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>| ListNode   |
                                              +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                              | val:  2    |
                                              | next: null |
                                              +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
[result: Ref89895]−−−>|    ListNode    |   
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   
                      | val: 1         |      +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | next: Ref11243 |−−−−−>| ListNode   |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                              | val: 10    |
                                              | next: null |
                                              +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note how `temp`'s value changed, so now it points to a different `ListNode`, the new one created with `new ListNode(2)`.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> How can i give some link here ? so that whenever `temp` is changed `result.next` starts pointing to new Object.

You can't, Java doesn't have any concept of references to variables, just references to objects (including arrays).

Comment: after temp = new ListNode(2), result.next is pointing where in your view ?

Comment: @UmairFarooq to the object returned by `new ListNode(10)` earlier. `temp` is just a pointer, not the actual object, therefore the pointer can point to a new object, and it no longer has any relation with the value it was previously pointing to

Comment: So we saved the reference in result.next and due to that the garbage collector won't clear up the previous object. Right ?

Comment: "But there is no ongoing link" , can you please help me to understand this and how can I correct this problem?

Comment: @UmairFarooq yes, someone is still referencing this object s it won't get GCed

Comment: Great. Refreshed my concepts again. You have got some clear concepts. Thanks for sharing the knowledge

Comment: @Vipin: I've added some Unicode-art to the above, hopefully that makes it clearer. In short: Java has no concept of references to *variables*, just references to *objects* (including arrays).

Comment: Drat, got my 2's and 10's reversed briefly. Hit refresh if you see `val: 2` near the bottom of the answer.

Comment: This is perfect explanation, I got the problem.How can i give some link here ? so that whenever temp is changed result.next starts pointing to new Object.

Comment: @Vipin: Fundamentally, you can't; I've added a note to the answer. I can't make out what that code is supposed to do, so I can't recommend an alternative.